# Sencha touch 2 segmented control check which button pressed

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have checked this out over the sencha touch examples that the items in the segmented button can be handled programmatically. The issue that i am facing currently is how to get the button that is pressed.

I need to store the index of the button that is pressed in my stores for further references so that when i launch the screen again I am able to select the buttons over the segmented control based on the selection.

I am handling the toggle event of the segmented button which takes three arguments:
- segmentedbutton
- button that is pressed
- pressed state.

I have access to the button when the event is generated but I am not able to find out how to get the index of the button.

Can someone provide some light on this ?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would go with a custom property in the button config, but you can also get the index of a newly selected button using `indexOf` on the `items` of the segmented button:

```
onSegmentedbuttonToggle: function(segmentedbutton, button, isPressed, eOpts) {
    if(isPressed){
        var index = segmentedbutton.getItems().indexOf(button);
        console.log("enabled button at index", index);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This amount of information will work too.. Looking for more precise solution. In case will get it will definitely share.